# Why my haml page is broken in source view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, capybara

When I run my test  it fails as below:
test Error message:

```
Failure/Error: page.should have_content 'Email'
     Capybara::Ambiguous:
       Ambiguous match, found 2 elements matching xpath "/html"
```

I searched online in how to structure haml file and I think its correct.

Here is My application.html.haml

```
!!! 5
%html
%head
  %title Hello
  = stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all'
  = javascript_include_tag 'application'
  = csrf_meta_tags

%body
  = yield
```

And here is: new.html.haml

```
%h1 Sign Up
= render partial: 'form'
```

And here is my partial form: _form.html.haml

```
= form_for @user do |f|
  - if @user.errors.any?
    %div.error_messages
      %h2 Form is invalid
      %ul
        - @user.errors.full_messages.each do |message|
          %li= message
  = f.label :full_name, 'Full Name:'
  = f.text_field :full_name
  %br

  = f.label :email, 'Email:'
  = f.text_field :email
  %br

  = f.label :password, 'Password:'
  = f.text_field :password
  %br

  = f.label :password_confirmation, 'Confirm Password:'
  = f.text_field :password_confirmation
  %br

  = f.submit 'Sign Up'
```

As you can see from the view source page, the closing  tag is at the top beside the open tag and not at the end of page. Which why Capybara is complaining about.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html></html>
<head>
  <title>Hello</title>
  <link href="/assets/application.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="/assets/jquery.js?body=1"></script>
  <script src="/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1"></script>
  <script src="/assets/turbolinks.js?body=1"></script>
  <script src="/assets/application.js?body=1"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Sign Up</h1>
  <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/users" class="new_user" id="new_user" method="post"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="n6sYrcT+Z7LtaH1AwT6h5/knsdMFRzwDTXAWZh6VyfI=" /></div>  <label for="user_full_name">Full Name:</label>
    <input id="user_full_name" name="user[full_name]" type="text" />
    <br>
    <label for="user_email">Email:</label>
    <input id="user_email" name="user[email]" type="text" />
    <br>
    <label for="user_password">Password:</label>
    <input id="user_password" name="user[password]" type="text" />
    <br>
    <label for="user_password_confirmation">Confirm Password:</label>
    <input id="user_password_confirmation" name="user[password_confirmation]" type="text" />
    <br>
    <input name="commit" type="submit" value="Sign Up" />
  </form>
</body>
```

Am I missing anything here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything should be indented after the HAML html tag. This indentation lets HAML know how to nest your tags. Therefore, application.html.haml should be:

```
!!! 5
%html
  %head
    %title Hello
    = stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all'
    = javascript_include_tag 'application'
    = csrf_meta_tags

  %body
    = yield
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to indent all the content for the `html` tag:

```
!!! 5
%html
  %head
    %title Hello
    = stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all'
    = javascript_include_tag 'application'
    = csrf_meta_tags

  %body
    = yield
```

What you're doing is different:

```
!!! 5
%html
%head
  ...
```

This is telling haml to render a `html` tag with no embedded content, followed by a `head` tag which has embedded content. Indenting everything to be inside the `html` tag fixes this problem.